# ESP32 WebServer performance for 72xWS2812 RGB status

Tags: ajax, webserver, esp32

[**Webserver network timing**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdcRz.jpg)

Why AJAX is so laggy?
The most take a time: Initial connection.
How to speed up refreshing status of 72 rgb led?
I try to reach 100Hz.
Why AJAX is so laggy?
The most take a time: Initial connection.
How to speed up refreshing status of 72 rgb led?
I try to reach 100Hz.
Why AJAX is so laggy?
The most take a time: Initial connection.
How to speed up refreshing status of 72 rgb led?
I try to reach 100Hz.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";

WebServer server(80);
bool refresh = true;

void handleRoot() {
  String html = "<html><head><style>.led-box {width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 1px solid black; float: left; margin-right: 1px;}</style>";
  html += "<script>";
  html += "function updateLEDs() {";
  html += "  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();";
  html += "  xhr.open('GET', '/updateLEDs', true);";
  html += "  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {";
  html += "    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {";
  html += "      var colors = xhr.responseText.split(',');";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 72; i++) {
    html += "      document.getElementById('led" + String(i) + "').style.backgroundColor = '#' + colors[" + String(i - 1) + "];";
  }
  html += "    }";
  html += "  };";
  html += "  xhr.send();";
  html += "}";
  html += "setInterval(updateLEDs, 1000);";
  html += "</script></head><body>";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 72; i++) {
    html += "<div id='led" + String(i) + "' class='led-box'></div>";
  }
  html += "</body></html>";
  server.send(200, "text/html", html);
}

void handleUpdateLEDs() {
  String colorCodes = "";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 72; i++) {
    if (i > 1) colorCodes += ",";
    colorCodes += String(random(0xFFFFFF), HEX);
  }
  server.send(200, "text/plain", colorCodes);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.on("/updateLEDs", handleUpdateLEDs);
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ESP32 is a fairly sluggish little microcontroller to begin with, and you give it lots of unnecessary string processing to do on each HTTP request.

The worst bottleneck is your `handleRoot()` function - it dynamically assembles the exact same HTML document for every request. You do several hundreds of `String` concatenations *every time* someone GETs the root document. That's going to be ***slow***. Pre-assemble the string (e.g. using raw string literals in `setup()`), only return the value in `handleRoot()`.

```
String rootHtml;

void handleRoot() {
  server.send(200, "text/html", rootHtml);
}

void setup() {
  rootHtml = R"MYRAW(
<html><head><style>.led-box {width: 10px; height: 10px; border: 1px solid black; float: left; margin-right: 1px;}</style>
<script>
function updateLEDs() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/updateLEDs', true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      var colors = xhr.responseText.split(','); 
)MYRAW";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 72; i++) {
    rootHtml += "      document.getElementById('led" + String(i) + "').style.backgroundColor = '#' + colors[" + String(i - 1) + "];";
  }
  // ... etc  
}
```

The `handleUpdateLEDs()` function also does at least 144 string concatenations, which is probably not the fastest algorithm for assembling a large string. I'd experiment with `snprintf()` and friends.

Note that the Arduino `WebServer` class is not built for speed, it's built for simplicity. Experiment with [ESP IDF HTTP server](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/esp_http_server.html) to get better performance.

Comment: Or better, use websockets and avoid the overhead of setting up and tearing down the TCP connection each time.